# Naming zipped folders

Tags: command-line, bash, zip

I found a solution on how to zip all folders in a subfolder.

```
for i in */*; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done
```

The problem is that I want to name the .zip folders in the following way: `parentFolder_zippedFolder.zip`, but I want to maintain the code structure shown above, if possible. I would like it to look like

```
for i in */*; do zip -r "parentFolderName"" + ${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done
```

if possible, but I couldn't find a way to do this in a bash script.

Comment: Did you mean `${i%/*}`? And is `parentFolderName` the parent folder of `$i` or the folder from where you're running this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a folder structure like this:

```
./parent
./parent/child1
./parent/child1/data1
./parent/child2
./parent/child2/data2
```

Running this command: `for i in */*; do zip -r "${i/\//_}.zip" "$i"; done` will produce the following files:

```
./parent_child1.zip
./parent_child2.zip
```

The contents are the same as with the command in your question, with the names as you asked them to be.

Note that the zip files are created one level above, compared to your command. Your command creates the zip files inside the `parent` directory, my command creates them *alongside* the parent directory.

`${i/\//_}` is a `bash` substitution that replace the `/` character inside variable `i` with the `_` character. Since the `/` character is special in `bash`, we have to escape it, giving `\/`. If we were to replace the letter `t`, the substitution would be `${i/t/_}`.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for! But I still don't quite understand why this works. where exactly did you specify that the name of `i` should be `parent_child.zip`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant where did you specify that the path of `i` was `parent_child` and not the full pwd path.

Comment: Using the `echo` command in such cases helps understand what it happening. Run `for i in */*; do echo "${i/\//_}.zip"; done` and you will better understand how `i` is modified to become the zip name.

Comment: If I do that, it only prints me the file names... Should something else happen?

Comment: Nope, it's just a way to debug and understand what is happening. It helps understand what `"${i/\//_}.zip"` does.